# How do I/Can I Monitor Azure Storage Queue TPS

Tags: azure, queue, monitoring

The title pretty much speaks for itself.

I'm finding that my high traffic queues are at times randomly very, VERY sluggish. I'm not sure if I am hitting the 500TPS limit and don't know where to find this information or if I even can find this information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Storage does provide metrics which can optionally be anabled then analyzed. This may provide some of the data you're looking for. Just be careful about how you implement it as it could easily count against the 20k TPS per storage account limit.

I'd also recommend you instrument your solution so you can capture this type of telemetry within it. This can sometimes help identify its it the queue itself that's the issue or something within the application. I'd also strongly recommend that all queue operations be done via .NET use the asyncronous methods as this can boost overall performance.

PS - the queue scale target for storage accounts create after july 1, 2012 is 2,000tps, not 500. See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/11/02/windows-azure-s-flat-network-storage-and-2012-scalability-targets.aspx

Comment: I appreciate the info from the link. Our storage accounts were created before the upgrade, now we have that to think about...
 For the main issue, are you referring to setting up perfcounters? We were looking at that a while ago and it just fell to the wayside by bigger projects. Perhaps it's time to pick it up again.

Comment: There is no set perfcounter for queue throughput. Its something you'd have ot log on a application basis. but you could do things like store up the message counts for each process locally for a given period and write those counts out to a log. Then monitor that log. Alternatively, you could just log instances where you encounter that appears to be throttle related errors and then monitor for that. Regardless, proper instrumentation of the application is critical to remote issue analysis.